# Is it possible to use choose-tree mode with iTerm's tmux integration?

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I've discovered that iTerm is able to natively integrate with Tmux nicely, even over ssh. However I currently cannot find a way to use the `choose-tree` mode, which nicely displays all the available sessions and allows me to quickly switch between them. Is it possible to somehow invoke this command while in the `-CC` mode with iTerm?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC control mode sends the raw data from each pane to iTerm2 and relies on it to draw it in panes, there is no way for it to access the tree mode output. So you will have to use whatever mechanism iTerm2 provides to select panes instead.

Comment: ITerm does have a tmux sessions dashboard but it's inconvenient and glitchy. I guess I'll file a feature request for ITerm then.